# Test django model attribute values - e.g. Decimal

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to compare the attribute values of a Django model to values in a dict. However the test fails when i test in the debugger, due to the model attribute type being Decimal.  What's the best way to test so that the below passes

```
def create_or_update_if_diff(unique_id, defaults, model):
    try:
        instance = model.objects.get(unique_id=unique_id) 
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        instance = model.objects.create(unique_id=unique_id, **defaults)
        sys.stdout.write('New {} created: {}\n'.format(instance.__class__.__name__, instance.unique_id))
        return instance, True
    else:
        for key, value in defaults.items():
            if getattr(instance, key) != value:
                model.objects.filter(unique_id=unique_id).update(**defaults)
                sys.stdout.write('{}: {} updated \n'.format(instance.__class__.__name__, instance.unique_id))
                return instance, True
        return instance, False
```

Debugger test output

```
Out[1]: 'unit_price'
>>> key
Out[2]: 'unit_price'
>>> value
Out[3]: 5.2
>>> instance.unit_price
Out[4]: Decimal('5.20')
>>> getattr(instance, 'unit_price')
Out[5]: Decimal('5.20')
>>> instance.unit_price == value
Out[6]: False
```

Comment: You can convert value into decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from decimal import Decimal

attr = getattr(instance, key)
if isinstance(attr, Decimal):    
    value = Decimal(str(value))
if attr != value:
    ...
```